# JAXB Marshall XML Profile Filter

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling

I have the need to marshall an object into XML using JAXB.

The Marshall / Unmarshall code works fine, but now we want to filter the resulting XML based on an annotation.

**XmlProfile.java**

```
@Retention (RUNTIME)
@Target({TYPE, METHOD, FIELD})
public @interface XmlProfile {
    String[] value();
}
```

**FooPojo.java**

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class FooPojo {

    @XmlElement
    @XmlProfile("config")
    public String bar;

    @XmlElement
    @XmlProfile("operational")
    public String bartender;

    @XmlElement
    @XmlProfile({"config", "operational"})
    public String spy;

}
```

I read the JAXB documentation, but I have not found examples / topics on how to inject some code into the marshall process, different than the adapter or the eventHandlers.

In particular I read about the Event Handlers, but what I found is the support of before marshal / after marshal events.

I expected to found a beforeFieldMarshal event but it is not possible, so I figured to write a piece of code that scans the current entity and set null to the properties not matching to the current profile:

```
private class ProfileListener extends Marshaller.Listener {

    private String profile;

    public ProfileListener(String profile) {
        this.profile = profile;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeMarshal(Object source) {
        if (source == null || profile == null || profile.length() == 0) return;

        Field[] fields = source.getClass().getFields();
        for (Field f : fields){
            XmlProfile xmlProfile = f.getAnnotation(XmlProfile.class);
            if (xmlProfile == null) continue;

            String[] annValues = xmlProfile.value();
            if (annValues == null 
                || annValues.length == 0 
                || findInArray(annValues)) {
                continue;
            }

            // Remove from object
            f.setAccessible(true);
            try {
                f.set(source, null);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        super.beforeMarshal(source); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    private boolean findInArray(String[] annValues){
        for (String annVal : annValues) {
            if (profile.equalsIgnoreCase(annVal)){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

The code works fine, also with nested object, this is the code I obtain:

**Working Pojo**

```
FooPojo fooPojo = new FooPojo();
fooPojo.bar = "Tijuana Cafe";
fooPojo.bartender = "Cynthia";
fooPojo.spy = "Antony Fisco";
fooPojo.phone = "555 555 555";
```

** Resulting XML for config profile:**

```
<fooPojo>
    <bar>Tijuana Cafe</bar>
    <spy>Antony Fisco</spy>
    <phone>555 555 555</phone>
</fooPojo>
```

** Resulting XML for operational profile:**

```
<fooPojo>
    <bartender>Cynthia</bartender>
    <spy>Antony Fisco</spy>
    <phone>555 555 555</phone>
</fooPojo>
```

but **has a functional bug** that I don't know how to solve:
the POJO is updated by the code, setting up null properties.

Is there a better way to do that? I can eventually clone the object and work on it, but I'm not sure it is the right way.

Comment: Using a Cloning util before the marshall the problem is solved but it is not efficient. Maybe using an afterMarshal filter and work on the built XML.